# Trying to add a item in a string list error

Tags: c#

So I am trying to put the regex result into a list.

```
List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
```

Is the list I am reffering to.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"RESPONSIVE\.constant\.user = {(?<userParams>.*?)}", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

                        Match match = regex.Match(text);

                        if (match.Success)
                        {
                            // Split up the values using comma
                            var keyValuePairs = match.Groups["userParams"].Value.Split(',');

                            // Split up each line using : as delimeter and clean up both sides, removing whitespace and single quote characters
                            var dict = keyValuePairs
                                .Select(kvp => kvp.Split(':'))
                                .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(), kvp => kvp[1].Trim().Trim(new char[] { '\'' }));

                            // Read name
                            var name = dict["name"];
                            usernames.Add(name);
                        }
```

is what I am trying to do but I get the following error:

```
Warning CS0649  Field 'Form1.usernames' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you need to instantiate (create) an instance of `usernames` in `Form1`.  Simply declaring it is not sufficient.

Comment: Are you sure the `usernames` you are adding to is the same one you have at top in your question?

Comment: @Tim the OP has instantiated it. I think-if it is the same one.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - I see that now.  Though it's a compiler warning, not an error.  It's not clear from the posted code where everything fits, but based on the warning something's amiss.

Comment: It doesnt add the string in the list.

Comment: Okay, split the declaration and assignment, put the declaration before the `Form1` constructor: `List<string> usernames;` and inside `public Form1(){..}` put `usernames = new List<string>();`

Comment: Same problem...

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning and not an error, in fact. Instead of

```
List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
```

Write

```
usernames = new List<string>();
```

This warning is displayed in a class like this:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    List<string> list; 
    public MyClass()
    {   
    } 
}
```

or

```
public class MyClass 
{
    List<string> list; 
    public MyClass()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
    } 
}
```

but not this one:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    List<string> list; 
    public MyClass()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
    } 
}
```